# Web service WSDL and discovery is not working correctly

Tags: web-services, wsdl

**Background:** We have a remote web server that has our web site and web service on it. We have access to this service and the site, but not the server directly as it is managed by another company.

**The Problem:** Our web services are operational and work fine, but we cannot connect to the web service because the WSDL specifies the soap address location as:

```
http://webserver/ourService.asmx
```

'Webserver' should be replaced with our site name:

```
http://ourSite.com/ourService.asmx
```

Because of this error we cannot add web references in Visual Studio or use the current WSDL file. We have to manually edit the WSDL, disco, and map files so that can connect to the service.

We have notified the admins that manage this, but they have apparently not been able to find the solution to this issue. Is there a specific property that must be set in IIS or in the website? I know the WSDL is generated automatically on the server, but is there any code that we need to put in the web service on our end for this to work? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a duplicate of the SO question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574768/a-wcf-service-behind-a-firewall-generates-a-wrong-wsdl-uri